# Merge Sort give me no output

Tags: c++, mergesort

i wrote this merge sort code inspired by deitel book (it use classes).
When i compile the code (with no error) i get the output of the not sorted array, but the second output doesn't appear, like it ignore that part of code.
The program terminate normally.

Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mergeSort(int*, int);


int main()
{

   const int DIM = 20;
   int vettore[DIM] = { 5, 10, 45, 214, 2, 14, 65, 87, 30, 21, 1, 24, 97, 
                        35, 64, 82, 14, 32, 98, 2};


   for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
       cout << vettore[i] << ' ';

   cout << endl;

   mergeSort(vettore, DIM);

   for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
       cout << vettore[i] << ' ';

   return 0;

}

void sortSubVector(int*, int, int, int); //prototipo
void mergeSort(int* vec, int dim)
{
    sortSubVector(vec, dim, 0, dim-1);
}

void merge(int*, int, int, int, int, int); //prototipo
void sortSubVector(int* vec, int dim,  int low, int high)
{
    if((high - low) >= 1 )
    {
        int middle1 = (high - low) / 2;
        int middle2 = middle1 + 1;

        sortSubVector(vec, dim, low, middle1);
        sortSubVector(vec, dim, middle2, high);

        merge(vec, dim, low, middle1, middle2, high);
    }
}


void merge(int* vec, int dim, int left, int middle1, int middle2, int right)
{
     int leftIndex = left;
     int rightIndex = middle2;
     int tempIndex = left; //indice vettore temporaneo

     int tempVector[ dim ]; //qui verranno posizionati gli elementi ordinati

   while(leftIndex <= middle1 && rightIndex <= right)
   {
       if(vec[leftIndex] <= vec[rightIndex])
           tempVector[tempIndex++] = vec[leftIndex++];
       else
           tempVector[tempIndex++] = vec[rightIndex++];
   }

  /* gli elementi di una metà sono stati tutti posizionati in ordine, ma 
     mancano gli elementi dell'altra metà */ 

     if(leftIndex == middle2) //la prima metà è stata completata
         while(rightIndex <= right)
             tempVector[tempIndex++] = vec[rightIndex++];
     else                    //la seconda metà è stata completata
         while(leftIndex <= middle1)
             tempVector[tempIndex++] = vec[leftIndex++];

   /*il vettore temporaneo è pieno e ordinato. Copiamolo nel vettore 
     originale*/

    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
       vec[i] = tempVector[i];
 }
```

Where is the problem? 
Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: "_The program terminate normally._" According to [this](https://ideone.com/BOabxd) no, it doesn't. It terminates with a runtime error. Did you try stepping through your code, to figure out what said error is?

Comment: I would suggest that you learn how to use a debugger first.

Comment: Use small, systematic cases so you can work through code by hand or more easily step through it in a debugger. For instance, your code "sorts" `{1,2,3}` into `{1,1,2}` (I think one of the `1`s is just an undefined accident), and crashes for me with `{1,2,3,4}` in an endless recursion.

Comment: i fixed the last for loop in   for(int i = left; i <= right; i++). now is very identical to book implementation, but doesn't still work. I'm at first year of university, i don't know how to use debugger yet

Comment: i use debugger and i received this error: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004014b0 in sortSubVector (vec=0x61ff04, dim=4, low=2, high=3) at mergeSort.cpp:12
12                      int middle1 = (high - low) / 2;
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004014b0 in sortSubVector (vec=0x61ff04, dim=4, low=2, high=3) at mergeSort.cpp:12
12                      int middle1 = (high - low) / 2;
(gdb) next
[Inferior 1 (process 5040) exited with code 030000000375]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments guys. I found the error.
in sortSubVector function, in middle1 variable i calculate (high - low) / 2
but in case of high = 3 and low = 2 i obtain a wrong index and i receive a segmentation fault error. i fixed it calculating middle1 = (low + high) / 2 and now it works!

thanks to you i learn to use debugger to find errors, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your scientific curiosity, but there is no need to implement a personal sort algorithm (unless you have a very good specific reason to do so).

Here is a more c++ like implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
void print(const T& array) {
    for (const auto& item : array) {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const int DIM = 20;
    std::array<int, DIM> vec = {5, 10, 45, 214, 2, 14, 65, 87, 30, 21, 1, 24, 97, 35, 64, 82, 14, 32, 98, 2};

    print(vec);

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    print(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Please consider the following points

- Use the containers provided by the standard library, such as `std::vector` and `std::array`.
- Use the algorithm provided by the standard library, such as `std::sort`.
- Don't use `using namespace std`
- Bob Martin suggests (in his book `Clean Code`) to solely use English naming for variables. Thus use `vec` instead of the Italian `vettore`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it to learn how merge sort works because it is required to pass my exam. I know that exist algorithms by std library, i learnt that by my book. I used italian name because i'm italian (yes, locic and stupid thing) but i have to learn use english word only like you say